# KVC along with associatedtype

Tags: swift, swift4, kvc

I have a Bindable protocol

```
protocol Bindable: class {
    associatedtype ObjectType: Any
    associatedtype PropertyType

    var boundObject: ObjectType? { get set }
    var propertyPath: WritableKeyPath<ObjectType, PropertyType>? { get set }

    func changeToValue(_ value: PropertyType)
}
```

I want to have a default implementation for changing a value

```
extension Bindable {

    func changeToValue(_ value: PropertyType) {
        boundObject?[keyPath: propertyPath] = value
    }
}
```

But this will throw an error saying:

> Type 'Self.ObjectType' has no subscript members

The definition of `propertyPath` is saying that it's a `KeyPath` for `ObjectType` so what's going on here? How can I tell the compiler that propertyPath really is the keyPath for changed object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should make `propertyPath` optional. This should work:

```
protocol Bindable: class {
    associatedtype ObjectType: Any
    associatedtype PropertyType

    var boundObject: ObjectType? { get set }
    var propertyPath: WritableKeyPath<ObjectType, PropertyType>{ get set }

    func changeToValue(_ value: PropertyType)
}

extension Bindable {

    func changeToValue(_ value: PropertyType) {
        boundObject?[keyPath: propertyPath] = value
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, that optional `KeyPath` was a problem. It's very confusing error though.

Comment: @ViktorKucera: I agree, error description is very confusing